# Why not just modify directly in the DB?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

I was reading this [blog post about the death of meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and it seems like Jeff and the crew are using the normal UI to modify tags. Excuse my ignorance, by why would that be? If you wanted to get rid of a tag such as "subjective," wouldn't it be easier and faster to run a "migration" at the DB level?

<strike>**Dumb joke:** (also, isn't "discussion" a metatag)?</strike>

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Please tell me so I can understand the rating system on meta; the downvotes strike me as odd.

Comment: Is this a joke? Do you seriously think we clicked the save button 10,000 times this weekend?

Comment: @waffles, that's a really great point: it's a stupid question because I imagine that something is possible that is too dumb to be possible (except that the moderators do use the UI exclusively, right?). So either it's a joke, I'm stupid, or I'm calling you guys stupid. Nice perspective!

Answer (score 3):

I believe they actually did use the DB initially; those tags were erased, and any post that ended up with no tags was tagged [[untagged]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/untagged). That tag shows up as created by `none`, so that seems to indicate it was part of a DB operation:

[Screenshot of the [untagged] creation http://mrozekma.com/so-untagged.png](http://mrozekma.com/so-untagged.png)

There's a [chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148/questions-tagged-untagged) about retagging all the [untagged] questions

Answer (score 0):

If the team were to modify the DB, then there is the possibility that they would end up with questions that had no tags. However, if they use the UI, they can also retag these questions appropriately.

Yes, `[discussion]` is a meta-tag, but considering that this *is* meta...

Comment: So they used the DB for all the questions that had more than one non-meta tag?

Comment: @Yar Quite honestly, I have no idea. I think a tag-deletion has only happened once or twice before.